# What can't I get this random quote generator to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to make a "Random Quote Machine" that randomly selects a quote from an array of 5 quotes and inserts the text into a paragraph on a webpage. The Machine uses HTML and JavaScript(jQuery). I suspect my error is pretty simple given how simple the project is.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Random Quote Machine</title>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="quotes.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Mason Cooley Quotes</h1>
        <div>
            <p id="quote"></p>

        </div>
        <button id="quoteGen">Generate A Random Quote</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
var quotes = ["Innocence is thought charming because it offers delightful possibilities for exploitation.",
"Every day begins with an act of courage and hope: getting out of bed.",
"Hatred observes with more care than love does.",
"To understand someone, find out how he spends his money.",
"The educated do not share a common body of information, but a common state of mind."
];

function getQuote() { 
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
}



$('#quoteGen').click(function() {
    $('#quote').text(quotes[getQuote()]);
});
```

Comment: Does your Javascript console show anything?

Comment: code is running before elements exist, use a ready handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your scripts are included in the `head` element, the `quoteGen` button doesn't exist in the DOM at the time that you try to bind an event handler to it. You need to either include the scripts just before the end of your `body` tag, or wrap your code in a DOM-ready event handler to ensure that the DOM exists as you expect it to when your code runs.

So, you could either go with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Random Quote Machine</title>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Mason Cooley Quotes</h1>
    <div>
        <p id="quote"></p>

    </div>
    <button id="quoteGen">Generate A Random Quote</button>

    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="quotes.js"></script>  
</body>

</html>
```

... or, use a DOM-ready handler, such as this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#quoteGen').click(function() {
        $('#quote').text(quotes[getQuote()]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Works just fine? 
http://jsfiddle.net/tj3dvz1m/.

make sure to run your code in a

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    Your code here.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The handler is being set before the #quoteGen dom node exists.

You need to move the inclusion of quotes.js to the end of your file, right before the closing of /BODY.

Or register the handler to be installed once the document is ready:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#quoteGen').click(function() {
    $('#quote').text(quotes[getQuote()]);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine. Credit to owner.

```
// Random Quotes

var Quotation=new Array()

Quotation[0] = "Time is of the essence! Comb your hair.";
Quotation[1] = "Sanity is a golden apple with no shoelaces.";
Quotation[2] = "Repent! The end is coming, $9.95 at Amazon.";
Quotation[3] = "Honesty blurts where deception sneezes.";
Quotation[4] = "Pastry satisfies where art is unavailable.";
Quotation[5] = "Delete not, lest you, too, be deleted.";
Quotation[6] = "O! Youth! What a pain in the backside.";
Quotation[7] = "Wishes are like goldfish with propellors.";
Quotation[8] = "Love the river's \"beauty\", but live on a hill.";
Quotation[9] = "Invention is the mother of too many useless toys.";

var Q = Quotation.length;
var whichQuotation=Math.round(Math.random()*(Q-1));
function showQuotation()
{document.write(Quotation[whichQuotation]);}
showQuotation();
```